# Serializing an IEnumerable of objects with Newtonsoft in Immediate Window chops the results

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, jsonserializer, immediate-window

We have tried this code that works in the class but fails in the Immediate Window:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = System.IO.File.CreateText("z:\\file.json");
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(file, myCollection);
file.Close();
```

Even if the Immediate Window returns "Expression has been evaluated and has no value" after each command, the file only has a part of the Json: the file ends abruptly in the middle of a word.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You are probably looking at the results on disk before the call to `file.Close()`.  Before the file is closed some of the JSON may be buffered in memory.  Also, in your real code you should close the `file` via a `using` statement rather than via an explicit `Close()` as this guarantees unmanaged resources will be disposed of in the event of an exception, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: But we really need to see a [mcve] to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dbc pointed out in a comment, the problem was a premature file inspection before properly calling

```
file.Close();
```

Thanks!